# Node: How Can I Import Web3 To Node.js?

Tags: web3js, nodejs, import

I'm trying to import the web3 library in Node.js so that I can handle Ethereum smart contract events, however I can't get the import to work.

I'm running Babel on each file to convert to es5, and the import in Node's index.js file looks like this:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

When I add that "import Web3 from 'web3'" statement I get a "scrypt" error:

```
webpack:///./node_modules/scrypt/index.js?:3
var scryptNative = __webpack_require__(!(function 
webpackMissingModule() { var e = new Error("Cannot find module 
'./build/Release/scrypt'"); e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'; throw e; } . 
()))

^

Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/scrypt'
at webpackMissingModule 
(webpack:///./node_modules/scrypt/index.js?:3:84)
at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/scrypt/index.js?:3:181)
at Object../node_modules/scrypt/index.js
```

This is my version of web3: (However, I have tried other versions which also don't work)

```
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
```

I've searched around but I can't find any solution to the above error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with `const Web3 = require("web3");`?

Comment: P.S.: Regardless of your question, I recommend that you remove the `^`, and also upgrade to `beta34`, which is the most stable version which I'm aware of.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the older syntax, but I'm already running Babel on all of my files (I'm importing React scripts) and I'm using "Import" in other places, so I might as well keep things consistent. Ok, I'll upgrade web3.

Comment: You'll actually be downgrading web3, since at present, the `^` brings you to `beta52` or later.